# file index with realtime search capabilities

Tags: gnome, files, indexing

I am curios if there is a software that indexes all my files and direcories, including external HD, possibly in real time allowing me or whoever access the HD to find the file up to date (something similar to GDrive + GDesktop).

Also, when I search for a specific file using Gnome Search the app is very slow, is there a faster way to search for a file or files? (including dir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmmm... how about this very basic text-file DIY idea? It only updates when you run it, could have a new "index" file every day or whenever you'd like.

```
 sudo find / -type f -print > allfiles.txt
```

Then just `grep "showmethis" allfiles.txt` to find things... see their man pages for more info.

---

Or try some of these software packages available:

**Basenji** - Cross-platform media indexing/search tool - https://launchpad.net/basenji

> Basenji is an indexing and search tool designed for easy and fast indexing
> of media collections. Once indexed, removable media such as CDs and
> USB sticks can be browsed and searched for specific files very quickly,
> without actually being connected to the computer. Besides file hierarchies
> and audio track listings, Basenji also presents extracted metadata
> (image dimensions, mp3 tags etc.) and content previews of indexed media in a
> clean and straightforward user interface.

[image: Basenji screenshot]

---

**Catfish** - Catfish is a handy file searching tool for Linux and UNIX. The interface is intentionally lightweight and simple, using only Gtk+3. You can configure it to your needs by using several command line options.

[image: Catfish image]

---

**Kfind** - KFind can be used to find files and directories on your system. Part of the KDE base applications, so probably wants ~150MB of dependencies installed too if you're not using other K stuff.

Some other command-line options too:

- doodle - a tool to search the meta-data in your files
- locate - maintain and query an index of a directory tree

  > updatedb generates an index of files and directories. GNU locate can be used to quickly query this index.
- mlocate - new implementation of locate, "improved"?

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  I was looking, for simplicity, at something with a GUI, my gf is slowly migrating from Win and the CLI is something she does not like very much.   Do you know if there is an app that searched for indexed files, without taking too long? What I really need is something that searches for files (or dir) and possibly inside files (mainly pdf and doc) faster then the standard gnome tool.

Comment: I think I saw one in the Software center (Synaptic, etc) a few years ago, it kept a database of files, probably with sizes too...  I'll try searching, you can too, but probably want all the repo sources activate (like main restricted universe multiverse, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu ). I'll update answer

Comment: @simplemind Added a bunch of programs that should work, if any are useful please select/check-mark an answer as correct (noticed you only selected for 1 of your 15 questions)